# What is the best way to store static data in Android application?

Tags: android, xml, database, storage

I have a bunch of data (each data entity has some properties like id, name...).

I want to store them statically in an Android application. What is the best way to do that? To allow reading them and access any entity in the data set?

What about using arrays.xml (one for IDs and the other for names)?

Comment: Do you need data to be persistent?

Comment: Look at [Android-Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: It depends on your data weight, if it is huge you should go for database else you can store it statically in res/values.

Comment: @Arfin it's a small data >> about 30 data entity, each entity has Id,name,description and descriptions small text (about 500 characters).

Comment: If less than 30 means its ok, you can save it inside re/values string.xml. Make all the field as a array of your own desired data type and fetch it in your activity class whenever required, but you need to maintain one more array for unique id of all the entities, while fetching "position" will be the main factor so don't disorder the data and the unique ids of individual entities. And by the way this will work completely as static you cant change values dynamically. k?

Comment: no, it's a fixed set of data, for read only.

Comment: yea its fine then you can save it in res/values/string.xml

Answer (score 0):

SQLite database.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.sg/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-12.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Or you can probably just store it in array.